# How to deal with leading zeros when formatting an int value

Tags: c#, string-formatting

have a bit of a blank. If I want to apply the following format (`## ### ###`) to an int value I would do this.

```
string myFormat = "## ### ###";
int myPin = 18146145;
Console.WriteLine(myPin.ToString(myFormat)); //18 146 145
```

Issue however is with the values of say `"02112321"` to be formatted as `"02 112 321"` applying this exact formatting `"## ### ###"`. the 0 in this case would fall away.

Comment: How about `$"{myStr.Substring(0,2)} {myStr.Substring(2,3)} {myStr.Substring(5,3)}`

Comment: Are you asking how to convert a string to an int? Or how to deal with leading zeroes?

Comment: The issue I had was with the leading zeros

Comment: @Arianule then you should edit your question to make that clear. The way it is, it appears that you're trying to change a string format to another

Comment: Good point. thanks. I updated the question to reflect the struggle with the leading zero

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the 0 as format specifier. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) :

> Replaces the zero with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, zero appears in the result string.

You can do like :

```cs
02112321.ToString("00 000 000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Edit:
As indicate by @olivier-jacot-descombes, I miss a point. The OP want format a integer from a string to a string. Example `"02112321"` to `"02 112 321"`.

It's possible with a intermediate conversion, string to int to string. With the example, this done `"02112321"` to `02112321` to `"02 112 321"` :

```
var original = "02112321";
var toInt = int.Parse(original, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var formated = toInt.ToString("00 000 000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: The OP wants to format a `string`, not an `int`.

Answer (score 9):

Formatting consists of converting a value to a string by giving it a certain shape. Therefore, formatting does not apply to strings (because they are already strings). You can convert the string to a number and then convert it back to string and apply the desired format.

```cs
string myFormat = "00 000 000";
string s = "02112321";
string formatted = Int32.Parse(s).ToString(myFormat); // ==> "02 112 321"
```

If you need leading zeroes, use the format string `"00 000 000"` instead of `"## ### ###"`.

Note that `Int32.MaxValue` is `2,147,483,647`. If you need to format lager numbers, use `Int64.Parse` allowing numbers up to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`.